# Is seeking in std::basic_streambuf underspecified in the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, standards

The C++ standard says ($27.6.3.4.2) that the effects of both `std::basic_streambuf::seekoff` and `std::basic_streambuf::seekpos` are defined separately for each class deriving from `std::streambuf`. But how can `std::istream`/`std::ostream` work then? The definition of the interface of the latter two classes has several assumptions about at least what the parameters of the `pubseekoff` / `pubseekpos` mean.

It seems that without a clarification on the part of `std::basic_streambuf`, not all subclasses that implement `std::basic_streambuf` interface could be used with the streams even if they support arbitrary seeking. For example, by the current specification, a subclass could say that in `MyStreamBuf::seekoff` the parameter `which = ios_base::in` ond `which = ios_base::out` controls the output and input sequence (note: reversed) respectively. I think it's quite counter-intuitive that a particular seeking operation can be specified as "supported, but with different interface", in addition to the usual "supported" and "unsupported". Or was that the intent of the Standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeking is very limited.  About all you can be sure will work is on any
stream is to seek to the beginning of the stream, seek to the end, or
seek to a position you got from `tell`.  And if the stream is
bidirectional, you have to seek each time you change the direction.

If you know more about the stream, you may be able to do more; on a
`stringstream`, for example, you can seek pretty much anywhere, and
seeking on the input doesn't affect the position in output, and vice
versa.  On an `fstream`, the semantics also depend on whether the stream 
was opened in text mode or in binary, and possibly on the actual file
behind the stream: if it's an `ifstream` opened on `"/dev/tty" (Unix) or
"CONS" (Windows), then you probably can't seek at all (but might not get
an error if you try).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Various variants of seeking operation can have different effects or be outright unsupported. But according to the spec it's possible to implement the seeking operation with a _entirely different_ semantics, e.g. seeking to the end when `ios_base::beg` is passed to `pubseekoff`. _That's_ what I find unintuitive.

Comment: @jons34yp That's what happens when you leave parts of the implementation up to the user.  It's possible to implement `operator+` on a user defined numeric type to mean subtraction.  There's really no way around this: the intent is clear, and the behavior of `std::filebuf` and `std::streambuf` are defined (sort of, at least---seek to the beginning of a `std::filebuf` connected to a keyboard is not going to implement the desired semantics, and there's not much the standard can do about it).